# Rendering Web Service results to Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, web

I am building a solution in ASP.NET which presents data onto an instance of the Leaflet Java mapping platform. On the initial load a procedure creates and SQL query executes it and the results are passed to the map - this works fine.

The problem starts when I try to make it dynamic with drop-down lists which utilize jQuery to listen for when they change. The idea being that when this happens the value from the drop-down is taken - inserted into the same query used at initialization with the results from that being output to the map - but it fails to render.

The following is the code I have on the drop-down:

```
        $("#MainContent_DropDownList1").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "services/AJAXMapping.asmx/GetNewData",
                dataType: "text",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data: { species: $(this).val() },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("Error: " + err.responseText.toString())
                },
                success: function (data) {


                    $("#testarea").html(data);

                    geojson.clearLayers();

                    geojson = L.geoJson((test), {
                        style: choroStyle,
                        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                    }).addTo(map);

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The Web Service simply invokes the same method used at initialisation return it as a string. In order to make sure the geoJSON coming back was correct I had jQuery put the contents of the return into a DIV on the page, if I copy and paste this into a javascript file within the solution and render it, it works fine.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this - its the final step - trust me to stumble here :\

Many thanks,

Terry Gooding

Comment: The above code is meant to say geojson = L.geoJson((data), {

Answer (score 0):

Just bind change event with .live or .delegate!!

```
$(document).delegate("#MainContent_DropDownList1", "change", function (event) {
               //your code
            });
```

Comment: Tried the above but the map is still not updating itself with the new data :\